How to use Train Signals for two trains that share some of the same railroad track?
I have two trains sharing some of the same track.  One train I want to only go to the red stations, and one train I want to only go to the orange stations.  I am trying to use Train Signals to prevent the two trains from colliding but so far I honestly have zero understanding of how these signals work.

Where in this setup should the appropriate signals be places to prevent trains from colliding and to prevent trains from being on the same part of the track at the same time? From what I've researched so far, I should be able to use block signals for this entire setup.

Put Block Signals on both sides of the track at the entrance to each station
In your diagram, you show only a single rail line at the chokepoint between the four stations. This means that that rail needs to support two different trains, each moving in both directions. This is a bad thing, because the only way to safely handle that is to make sure that only one train is ever outside of its station at a time.
Otherwise, if the red train leaves the north station (going south) while the orange train leaves the south station (going north), both will be on the track at the same time. If the red train reaches the junction first, you will have a deadlock where the two trains are facing each other and neither can move forward.
To ensure that only one train is on the track at a time, avoid placing any signals on the shared track. Instead, put block signals on both sides of the track at the point where each station's specific track branches off from the shared track, and then use trains which have locomotives at both ends (so that they can turn around without needing track).
The important parts are:

Keep the shared track as a single block (do not place any signals in the middle of it which would break it up)
Every signal must be bidirectional (which is accomplished by placing a signal on both sides of the track), since trains move in both directions on the same track.

Unfortunately, the efficiency of this setup will be quite low. I recommend moving to a multiple-track solution, so that you can have a dedicated track for each direction (like lanes on a road).

This works! I'm not too concerned about efficiency, since the items the trains bring in I don't consume as fast.  Now - could I instead place the block signals on each side of the track slightly down the track before the stations as well (that way, it speeds the efficiency up just a bit?)

@TimmyJim Yes - as long as there are no signals on the shared portion of the track, the signals can be as far up as you like. When I wrote "The entrance to each station," I meant "The point at which the track for each station branches off from the shared track." I will clarify that in my answer.
